# Water is leaking from basement toilet. help

Tags: plumbing, drainage, septic, flooding

I bought this house that was without electricity for 8 months (water pipes froze too).
I have a septic system.
I've removed toilet in the basement and plugged septic pipe (it was filled with water)...
But water is still seeping through that floor hole...

Q: Where is it coming from?
Q: Am I supposed to have a septic pump?

I have a septic alarm in my garage - but I think pump breaker might be off for an actual pump in electrical panel....

[toilet pipe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0zyt.jpg)
[electrical panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1472.jpg)
[septic alarm?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diQJO.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If water is coming up through the pipe then it is because either your sewer is clogged, you septic tank is full or the leaching field has failed. What you are seeing is a sewage backup. It could be ground water entering your septic tank, or it could also be sewage from elsewhere in the house.  The basement toilet is the lowest drain in the house and this is where the water comes out.

You should check your tank.  If it's full of liquid then there's an issue with your leaching field. If its full of solids then it needs to be pumped. If it is not full, then there is a clog in your main sewer and that needs to be cleared in order for the contents of your drain pipes to empty.

Comment: If septic pump is off - could that be what causes a problem?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "septic pump", I sort of assumed you meant sump pump.  Do you mean a sewage/effluent pump? You would only need this if you lowest point is above the septic tank

Comment: as it turned out my septic system is a "mound" type septic built in 2000, thus higher the the ground elvel - that's why i needed effluent pump. toilet was leaking because  effleunt pump wasn't working. I've replaced 4 float switches and a pump - and everything is back to working state again.